# Understanding why Shapiros Inequality doesnt always hold

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to understand the following inequality. It is known as Shapiros bound. Let us be given non negative numbers $x_{i}$ with $x_{1}=x_{n+1}$ and $x_{2}=x_{n+2}$. Shapiro conjectured that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_{i}}{x_{i+1} + x_{i+2}} \geq \frac n2$$ holds. 
However this has been shown to be not true in general. The equality holds for even $n\leq12$
and odd $n\leq23$, but apart from that there are several known counter-examples. Wikipedia lists for example $(0, 42, 2, 42, 4, 41, 5, 39, 4, 38, 2, 38, 0, 40)$. To me this seems quite random and the other example on wikipedia maybe even more so.

My intuition would have been that simply choosing all the values cleverly but the same would be the best one could do, like for example choosing $x_{i}=\frac 12$ witch works well for the small n case. Since we know nothing about any particular $x_{i}$ it seemed reasonable to treat all of them the same way.

So I assume there is some structure in the counter example that i am missing. Perhaps they have been constructed by the help of some number theoretic theorem or there is some geometric interpretation i am unaware of.

The literature i found is rather focused on proving why the bound holds for the cases listed above, but i would rather like to understand what makes it fail. Can anyone help me build an intuition why increasing $n$ changes the behaviour of the inequality and what makes any of the known counter examples work better than choosing all $x_{i}$ to be the same?